# How do I use joi to validate phone numbers in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose-schema, joi

I'd like to use joi in node.js to validate the user's phone number in a schema.

The schema is as follows:

```
phone: {
    type: Number,
    unique:true,
  },
```

country code will be default: INDIA(+91). The number will change.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at npmjs.com i'm sure will find there what you need.

Comment: @Molda I've tried a variety of packages, including validator(isMobilePhone) and joi-phone-number, but none of them work. I also tried it with regex, but it didn't work out as well. As a result, I deleted it. maybe I am doing something wrong in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional package like that https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-phone-number

or

You can validate a phone number as a string with a regex like that :

```
joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]{10}$/).messages({'string.pattern.base': `Phone number must have 10 digits.`}).required()
```

or

You can extend joi to have an custom validator for phone number validation like that :

```
Joi.object({
phone: Joi
    .string()
    .custom((value, helper) => {
        // you can use any libs for check phone
        if (!checkPhone(value)) {
            return helper.message("phone is incorrect")

        return value

    })
}).validate({
   phone: '+79002940163'
});
```

For more information on custom validations please check : https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#anycustommethod-description

Comment: I'd like to use regex as a solution, but I'm not sure where to place this code. I'm new to node.js, to be honest.